# Where does 'article_set' come from in Django?

Tags: django, templates, django-models, pinax

I am currently working on a Django/Pinax application (I'm sure my question is not Pinax-specific, that's why Pinax's not mentioned in the theme title), and I'm trying to figure out how the whole framework works. Right now, I have to write a view to pass data to a template. I've only seen it done in the django manual: In the manual, ObjectName.objects.all() is simply passed to render_to_response(). My task is somewhat more complicated, so I've tried to understand how it is done in a pinax application 'profiles', and failed completely.

So, `profile.html` template file has a line like this:

```
{% for article in other_user.article_set.all %}
```

'other_user' is an instance of the 'User' class passed to render_to_response() in views.py. Ok, but article_set is not its class variable. I've failed to find article_set description anywhere in the application code, but found more occurrences of something looking like the same form of call:

```
{% for bookmark_instance in other_user.saved_bookmarks.all.select_related %}
```

Searching Django docs only resulted in [this](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/) page, not telling what 'article_set' exactly is.

What is article_set? Where is it defined and how does it work? Any answers or just documentation links are strongly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [documentation on following the "backward" relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

There are also [some examples](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/).

Answer (score 1):

It's an [artificial field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) created by a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` from the `Article` model.