# Django Tutorial: Where does the other objects come from?

Tags: python, django

I have been reading and following the Django Tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/ I am running Django 1.3.1, and Python 2.7.3 on Xubuntu 12.04 LTS virtual machine with 512 MB RAM if that matters.

Actually I found the exact question, but the reference seems to be out of date. Does anyone have a viable link to the reference? [Where does 'article_set' come from in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303923/where-does-article-set-come-from-in-django)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'article_set' is a dummy name of model.

Comment: It happens a lot, like in the tutorial you make a model called Polls, and then you call from that object other objects e.g. poll.choice_set.all

Comment: Where did the choice_set come from, there is a class called Choice, but where do these come from?

Comment: Why don't use Django>1.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does ForeignKey lookups to establish relations between related objects.
These relations are added dynamically as accessors suffixed by `_set`

```
def get_accessor_name(self):
    # This method encapsulates the logic that decides what name to give an
    # accessor descriptor that retrieves related many-to-one or
    # many-to-many objects. It uses the lower-cased object_name + "_set",
    # but this can be overridden with the "related_name" option.
    if self.field.rel.multiple:
        # If this is a symmetrical m2m relation on self, there is no reverse accessor.
        if getattr(self.field.rel, 'symmetrical', False) and self.model == self.parent_model:
            return None
        return self.field.rel.related_name or (self.opts.object_name.lower() + '_set')
    else:
        return self.field.rel.related_name or (self.opts.object_name.lower())
```

Code in Django sources that does this (`models/related.py`)

Comment: Do they keep the capitalization? Also thank you very much.

Comment: No, they do not keep capitalisation. The code above shows that the model name is converted to lower case `self.opts.object_name.lower()`.